# How to handle data with variable spaces in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read data with variable spaces using pandas.read_csv. One of the columns is a name having a space in itself. To give an idea here's how the head of the data looks like

```
ACM00078861  17.1170  -61.7830   10.0    COOLIDGE FIELD (UA)            1947 1993  13896
AEM00041217  24.4333   54.6500   16.0    ABU DHABI INTERNATIONAL AIRPOR 1983 2017  35306
AEXUAE05467  25.2500   55.3700    4.0    SHARJAH                        1935 1942   2477
```

What I have tried so far:

```
 df=pd.read_csv(path, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

It gives me this error, Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 2, saw 11

Then I tried to use

```
df=pd.read_csv(path, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False)
```

But, this just skips the bad lines and as a result, a lot of data is skipped. Even after that, it's not able to keep the column containing names (column index 4) under one column as delim_whitespace=True reads the spaces in their name as separate columns.

I also tried using

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep="\s{2,}", engine="python", header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
```

and but this reads "ABU DHABI INTERNATIONAL AIRPOR 1983 2017" under one column as there is single space between them.

I thought about manually editing the spaces in the data file but it's a lot of data and I've several instances like the one in row 2 here.

Is there a way that I could specify pandas to read columns as the info supplied by the data file which looks like this

```
   Variable   Columns

   ID            1-11   
   LATITUDE     13-20   
   LONGITUDE    22-30    
   ELEVATION    32-37   
   STATE        39-40   
   NAME         42-71   
   FSTYEAR      73-76   
   LSTYEAR      78-81   
   NOBS         83-88
```

Or is there a better way to handle such irregular spaced data?

Comment: Try `df = pd.read_fwf(path)` -- looks like your format is consistent enough for `fwf` to read it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that would be the advised method but it's not able to parse correctly out of the box, given that the OP has an additional file that specifies the column widths, they could parse this to construct the list of tuples that can be passed to `read_fwf` to read it correctly, would answer but a bit busy at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First data you can read from file and then use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) with parameters `colspecs` and `names`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file', sep="\s+")
print (df1)
    Variable Columns
0         ID    1-11
1   LATITUDE   13-20
2  LONGITUDE   22-30
3  ELEVATION   32-37
4      STATE   39-40
5       NAME   42-71
6    FSTYEAR   73-76
7    LSTYEAR   78-81
8       NOBS   83-88

n = df1['Variable'].tolist()
c = df1['Columns'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int).apply(tuple, 1).tolist()
print (n)
['ID', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'ELEVATION', 'STATE', 'NAME', 'FSTYEAR', 'LSTYEAR', 'NOBS']
print (c)
[(1, 11), (13, 20), (22, 30), (32, 37), (39, 40), (42, 71), (73, 76), (78, 81), (83, 88)]

a=[]
for i in c:
    a.append(tuple(np.subtract(i,(1,1))))
print (a)
[(0, 10), (12, 19), (21, 29), (31, 36), (38, 39), (41, 70), (72, 75), (77, 80), (82, 87)]


df = pd.read_fwf(file, header=None, colspecs=c, names=n)
print (df)

           ID  LATITUDE  LONGITUDE  ELEVATION  STATE  \
0  CM00078861   17.1170    -61.783       10.0    NaN   
1  EM00041217   24.4333     54.650       16.0    NaN   
2  EXUAE05467   25.2500     55.370        4.0    NaN   

                            NAME  FSTYEAR  LSTYEAR   NOBS  
0             OOLIDGE FIELD (UA)      947      993  13896  
1  BU DHABI INTERNATIONAL AIRPOR      983       17  35306  
2                         HARJAH      935      942   2477
```

Comment: I forgot to change colspecs=a in the edit. Everything else works well. Thanks for your solution.